# JSON parse error in Spring rest controller taking post request from android volley

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, android-volley, spring-restcontroller

Getting following exception in Spring boot server:
JSON parse error: Unrecognized token  was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null'); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException

while receiving POST request from Volley-android into Spring Rest Controller

```
 public class RegistrationCredential {
 @NotEmpty(message = "MacId is mandatory")
 @JsonProperty("macId")
 private String macId;
 @NotEmpty(message = "Mobile number is mandatory")
 @JsonProperty("mobileNo")
 private String mobileNo;
 ....
}
```

Added @JsonProperty("name") tag in model

```
@PostMapping(consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,    MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE},
      produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,     MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE})
public ResponseEntity<String> vendorMobileRegistration(@Valid     @RequestBody final RegistrationCredential credential) {}
```

Excerpt From Volley implemenettaion:

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, SpotPollingURLs.REGISTRATION_URL, new Response.Listener <String>() {
            @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            System.out.println("Getting response frome url --- "+response);
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                String status = jsonObject.getString("status");
                String messageCode = jsonObject.getString("MessageCode");
                String message = jsonObject.getString("message");

                if (status.equals("success") && messageCode.equals("MOBILE_REGISTERED_SUCCESSFULLY")) {
                    sendOTP(mobile, "send");
                    customDalog(mobile);
                } else if (status.equals("success") && messageCode.equals("MOBILE_NUMBER_ALREADY_REGISTERED")) {
                    new CustomToast().showToast(getContext(), view, message);
                } else if (status.equals("error")) {
                    new CustomToast().showToast(getContext(), view, message);
                } else {
                    new CustomToast().showToast(getContext(), view, "Something went wrong check your connection");
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            System.out.println("Getting error -- "+error);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }){

        @Override
        public Map <String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
            return headers;
        }

        @Override
        protected Map <String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("mobileNo", mobile);
            params.put("macId", uniqueId);
            return params;
        }
    };
```

Comment: can you provide sample request value?

Comment: {
    "mobileNo": "8961604460",
    "macId": "jjdc9kjnsd9"
}

Comment: did you try using toString() while trying to parse?